# Returning data via WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8, geolocation

I want to return `latitude` and `longitude` variables via WCF to show user's location on the map. I can return the `latitude`, but can't do the same thing with the `longitude`, because method returns only one value. I thought about returning array, but don't know how to do that. Here is WP code:

```
    void proxy_getUsrLatCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.getUsrLatCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid MyGrid = new Grid();
        MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        MyGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);

        Rectangle MyRectangle = new Rectangle();
        MyRectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        MyRectangle.Height = 20;
        MyRectangle.Width = 20;
        MyRectangle.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        MyRectangle.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);

        MyGrid.Children.Add(MyRectangle);

        Polygon MyPolygon = new Polygon();
        MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(2, 0));
        MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(22, 0));
        MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(2, 40));
        MyPolygon.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        MyPolygon.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        MyPolygon.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
        MyPolygon.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);

        MyGrid.Children.Add(MyPolygon);

        MapOverlay MyOverlay = new MapOverlay();
        MyOverlay.Content = MyGrid;
        MyOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0, 0.5);
        MapLayer MyLayer = new MapLayer();
        MyLayer.Add(MyOverlay);
        myMap.Layers.Add(MyLayer);

        float gLat = float.Parse(e.Result);
        myMap.Center = new GeoCoordinate(gLat, gLong);
        MyOverlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(gLat, gLong);      
    }
```

Comment: create a class that has both and return it, you have to decorate it with [DataContract]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define a class to hold both properties, and use it as the return value:

```
class Point
{
    public string Lat {get;set;}
    public string Lon {get;set}
}
public Point getUsrLocation(string uName)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext data = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    return (from s in data.Users where s.usrName == uName select new Point(){Lat=s.usrLat,Lon=s.usrLong}).Single();
}
```

Comment: could you tell me how I would get returned value, because I'm getting an error trying to do it this way: `float gLat = float.Parse(e.Result.Point.Lat);`

Comment: @Leek Did you generate your client proxy via **Add service reference**? If so your client code is now likely out of date.  Right-click your service reference and select **Update**

Comment: @MickyDuncan, I did and I have this class in my service reference, but still keep getting this error: `'PhoneApp1.ServiceReference1.Point' does not contain a definition for 'Point' and no extension method 'Point' accepting a first argument of type 'PhoneApp1.ServiceReference1.Point' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Please try e.Result.Lat instead.